# How to get parameterise a string separated by commas with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
{{tagName(21, 'hello, jane','smith')}}
```

I'm trying to use regex to `match()` this string to result in:

```
[0] = tagName
[1] = 21
[2] = 'hello, jane'
[3] = 'smith'
```

The parameter part of the string can grow. That is to say, it may have more or less parameters and the regex needs to be "greedy" yet knows how to group them up.

I've been trying something like that: `^\{\{([^\(]+)\({1}(.*)\){1}\}\}`

But this results in:

```
[0] = tagName
[1] = 21, 'hello, jane','smith'
```

What should I do to my regex to get the results I want?

Comment: Implement it in 2 regexes. It is fine to not put everything into a single unreadable monster.

Comment: @zerkms I wouldn't mind using 2 regexes. In fact, I tried, but I still struggle with parameterising the comma separated part of the string.

Comment: Just a question that may possibly discredit some of the answers already posted.. can the string parameters contain `\'`? If so, that'll make matching strings a little harder.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `{`, `}`, `(`, `)` with empty string; match `[a-z]+`, `\d+`, `'.+'` followed by `,` or end of input

```js
var str = "{{tagName(21, 'hello, jane','smith')}}";

var res = str.replace(/\{|\}|\(|\)/g, "")
          .match(/([a-z]+)|\d+|('.+')(?=,)|('.+')(?=$)/ig);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: The replace match can be expressed more readable (?) with `/[{}()]/g`

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome! +1! Just one more edge case, I notice that `"hello,smith"` will get separated as `["hello", "smith"]`.

Comment: @Carven Is `"hello,smith"` surrounded by single quotes? Similarly to example string at original Question? e.g., `'hello,smith'`?

Comment: @guest271314 Ideally, the single and double quotes can be used interchangeably. But it's okay if this isn't possible within regex as I can use JS to do an if/else check to replace them.

Comment: @Carven You should be able to adjust `RegExp` to include `(".+")(?=,)|(".+")(?=$)` to match double quotes followed by one or more characters followed by double quotes. Or possibly, untested `(('|").+('|"))(?=,)`

Comment: @guest271314 Oh.. yea, you got a point there. haha... So it's probably left with values which have commas without spaces like `hello,smith`

Comment: @Carven _"So it's probably left with values which have commas without spaces like `hello,smith`"_ Not certain what you mean?

Comment: @guest271314 I meant, let's say I have this: `var str = "{{tagName(21, 'hello, jane','smith', 'hello,john')}}";` The last element `'hello,john'` will get split up as `['hello', 'john']` in the current regex.

Comment: @Carven `["tagName", "21", "'hello, jane','smith'", "'hello,john'"]` was result, here, given `var str = "{{tagName(21, 'hello, jane','smith', 'hello,john')}}";` , using approach at Answer

Comment: Ahh... I know what's the problem now... It was because I had extra spaces between the braces like so: `{{ tagName(21, 'hello, jane','smith', 'hello,john') }}`

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using two regexes, you can return a new array with function name and concat all the parameters onto that array.

With ES6 you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```js
const str = "{{tagName(21, 'hello, jane','smith')}}";
const result = str.match(/^\{\{([^\(]+)\({1}(.*)\){1}\}\}/);

console.log([
  result[1], 
  ...result[2].match(/^\d+|'.*?'/g)
])
```

In ES5 you'll have to [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the parameters onto the array containing the function name as its first item:

```js
var str = "{{tagName(21, 'hello, jane','smith')}}";
var result = str.match(/^\{\{([^\(]+)\({1}(.*)\){1}\}\}/);

console.log([result[1]].concat(result[2].match(/^\d+|'.*?'/g)))
```

In reality, you could `concat` in ES6, but

Answer (score 0):

So far I've manage to come up with the following:

```
([A-Za-z]+)|('.*?'|[^',\s\(]+)(?=\s*,|\s*\))
```

Tested on https://regex101.com